# Expose Rust function through FFI with c bindings

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm creating a Rust library and want to expose my Rust functions through c bindings to `Dart`. This question is just related to the setup of actually exposing the Rust function through C bindings and not on how to call it in `Dart`.
This is my function which I want to expose through `FFI`:

```rust
pub fn create_channel(credential: String) -> Result<String, iota_streams::core::Error> {
    let seed = create_seed::new();

    // Create the Transport Client
    let client = Client::new_from_url(&dotenv::var("URL").unwrap());
    let mut author = Author::new(&seed, ChannelType::SingleBranch, client.clone());

    // Create the channel with an announcement message. Make sure to save the resulting link somewhere,
    let announcement_link = author.send_announce()?;

    // This link acts as a root for the channel itself
    let ann_link_string = announcement_link.to_string();

    // Author will now send signed encrypted messages in a chain
    let msg_inputs = vec![credential];

    let mut prev_msg_link = announcement_link;
    for input in &msg_inputs {
        let (msg_link, _seq_link) = author.send_signed_packet(
            &prev_msg_link,
            &Bytes::default(),
            &Bytes(input.as_bytes().to_vec()),
        )?;
        println!("Sent msg: {}", msg_link);
        prev_msg_link = msg_link;
    }
    Ok(ann_link_string)
}
```

The `credential` String is supposed to be just a stringified json object. Which I want to provide from `Dart` through C bindings into Rust and then use inside my `create_channel` function. But I don't know how to define the type of my `credential` parameter, because it would come in as a C type and then would need to be converted to Rust.

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn create_channel(credential: *const raw::c_char) -> String {
    streams::create_channel(credential).unwrap()
}
```

Right now I'm just defining the parameters of my `extern` function to be off type `c_char` but I would then need to convert this `C` type to a Rust `String` or `&str`. So that I can use it inside of my actual `create_channel` function written in Rust.

As what types should I define the `credential` parameter and how would I convert the `c_char` into a `String` or `&str?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust has the convenient `CStr` and `CString` types, you can use [`Cstr::from_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.from_ptr) to wrap the raw string and then call [`to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html#method.to_str) on that. Of course you need to do some error handling here for cases where the string isn't valid UTF-8.